# Can't uninstall Gnome Shell Extension

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

Gnome Shell 3.18.5 notified me some extensions needed updating. I visited https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ from Firefox, updated the Firefox extension, and now I want to uninstall some of the Gnome extensions, for example the following one.

> **Removable Drive Menu by fmuellner**
>   System extension
>
> A status menu for accessing and unmounting removable devices.

Hovering the mouse on *System extension*, I read the following tooltip.

> System extension should be uninstalled using package manager. See about page for details.

The *About* page says:

> What is *System extension*? How to uninstall it?
>
> System extension is installed to system-wide location (usually /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions). Such extension may be used by any PC user, however it can be uninstalled only by system administrator (root). To uninstall system extension use your distro's package manager or ask your system administrator.

I looked through Synaptic but don't see this extension. How do I remove it?

These are the extensions I want to remove.

- [Applications Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/)
- [Places Status Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/8/places-status-indicator/)
- [Removable Drive Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7/removable-drive-menu/)
- [Workspace Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/)
- [Pomodoro](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/53/pomodoro/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Launch `gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Search "Extensions" in right menù
3. Select the extension and click on "Remove"

[image: an example]

Comment: Worth noting that `tweak tool` will only uninstall local extensions (but not system wide extensions - the _Remove_ button will be greyed out for those ones)

Comment: some of my extensions have a grayed-out remove button (e.g. I can not remove them)

Comment: The "REMOVE" buttons are no longer there in gnome-shell 3.26.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Dorian Click on an item and it will appear in the Software app with a remove button, which for no apparent reason failed to remove my nonloadingsinceupgrading1904to1910 Arc Menu.

Answer (score 26):

Since the remove buttons are no longer available in gnome-shell 3.26, the only way I know is deleting the extension directory itself.

**With Nautilus**

1. Open Nautilus and show hidden files (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>).
2. Go to your home folder.
3. Navigate to `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
4. Delete the directory of the unwanted extension.
5. Reload gnome-shell. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

**The macho way**

1. Open the console.
2. Go to the extensions directory: `cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
3. List the extensions and get the name of the unwanted extension: `ls -l`
4. Delete the extension directory: `rm -r extension@author`
5. Reload gnome-shell. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 23):

There are two folders for gnome-shell extensions:

1. `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` for user-side
2. `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` for system-side

Comment: To list all extensions in both directories: `ls -d -1 /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/* ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*`

Answer (score 7):

Michael,

I had the same problem with the same extensions. The problem is that they are "System Extensions" and not in the normal location of `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` as others have said. Instead, "System Extensions" are installed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

To remove:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
sudo rm -rf apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Repeat as necessary.

Finally, you'll want to reload the shell: `Alt+F2 r`

Comment: March 2024 and still works perfectly (in Debian 12.5) Should now be the accepted answer since `gnome-tweak-tool` remove buttons have since been deprecated and not every Linux system can use the `Extensions` add-on in Firefox

Answer (score 4):

Go to software -> add-on, you will see your extensions there, just remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Use command `gnome-extensions uninstall extension@author`
to uninstall any unwanted extension. After that reload gnome-shell by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

e.g This is how you remove the pomodoro extension from your machine,

```
mridul@mridul-PC:~$ gnome-extensions list
set-columns@maestroschan.fr
desktop-icons@csoriano
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
pomodoro@arun.codito.in
mridul@mridul-PC:~$ gnome-extensions uninstall pomodoro@arun.codito.in
mridul@mridul-PC:~$ gnome-extensions list
set-columns@maestroschan.fr
desktop-icons@csoriano
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Edit: Thanks [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) for pointing out that this method is not working on system extensions. Though it's working for local extensions. Will look into it and update my answer..

Comment: This won’t help with system extensions, which is the whole point of the question.

Comment: But the command listed all extension both from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` & `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Is there any other location where system extensions get saved?

Comment: Can it uninstall extensions from both?

Comment: You are right !! This is'nt removing system extensions and not showing any error as well..

Answer (score 1):

Head to https://extensions.gnome.org/local. Install the Chrome / Firefox native connector for GNOME Extensions, and then you will see your GNOME extensions listed on that page. From there you can remove them and configure them without deleting files manually.

Answer (score 0):

its simple , had the same problem,
use yum to list the installed packages:

```
sudo yum list installed gnome-shell*
```

look to the particular extension in the installed packages and remove:

```
sudo yum remove <your extension>
```

Log out and log in

Answer (score 0):

The one which worked for me was to uninstall the package called `gnome-shell-extensions`.

I use arch linux so I did `sudo pacman -Rns gnome-shell-extensions`.

Those who use other than arch linux, please edit the answer and add the command for their distro.