# Gnome not booting on Fedora after upgrade but gnome-classic does

Tags: fedora, gnome

I restarted Fedora (32) after an upgrade having not restarted for around a week. After putting in password it hangs at a grey screen. I tried booting earlier kernel but no difference.
I can boot if I choose gnome-classic though. I looked in logs for previous boot and can see some errors:

Logs: https://pastebin.com/6dq52mxN

Comment: Did you try to disable Gnome shell extensions ? It seems there are a known source of issues (see the comments here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1787362). 
Also, see here for how to do it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353615/cant-uninstall-gnome-shell-extension

Comment: Yes and it's working now, think it was possibly 'turn off display' extension. Why on earth an extension would stop gnome booting is beyond me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with logging in a text console, e.g. Ctrl + Alt + F2 and then running.

```bsh
mkdir -p "$HOME/save"
mv "$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions" "$HOME/save"
```

This will remove all installed Gnome extensions. I've noticed some errors related to them. Try logging in after that.

---

In case it doesn't help again go to a text console (make sure you're not logged on) and run:

```bsh
mkdir -p "$HOME/save"
mv "$HOME/.local" "$HOME/.config" "$HOME/save"
```

This will remove all your settings but will most likely fix the issue that you're having.